# pgadmin4 : server won't start

Tags: linux, postgresql, fedora

I have this error message trying to start pgadmin4 web interface from the desktop helper on fedora 28/postgresql 10 :

```
Failed to launch the application server, server thread exiting.
```

Though, it appears that I can start it typing :

```
sudo pgadmin4
```

in the alt-F2 dialog. So I guess it is a permission issue but I have nothing relevant in the logs to elaborate on the matter.

Any hint would be welcome.

Comment: Is it supposed to run without `sudo`? What happens if you run it in a terminal?

Comment: Actually I don't know, I tried to find the info but without success, pgadmin3 did. And the terminal does not say much except that firefox is not supposed to be run as root.. To what I do agree.

Comment: I have a little progress : I can now start it from the command line with : sudo python3 /usr/../../pgadmin4.py : it starts in the user browser so I guess this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran those instructions first about the system permissions :
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.x/server_deployment.html
and then came up with this pgadmin4.service as it seems that the desktop helper does not help at all :

```
[Unit]
Description=Pgadmin4 Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User= root
Group= root

Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the solution I found : it does run in the user environment and can be enabled as a service.